# SpreadsheetML - Errors and Validation

Tags: c#, xml, excel, spreadsheetml

I generate a SpreadsheetML file for MS Excel in my C# project. This worked since some changes yesterday. Now I have issues opening it. It comes up with the error:

XML PARSE ERROR:  Null or missing attribute value
  Error occurs at or below this element stack:

I already narrowed it down to a single table with the issue, but it has 7000+ rows with around 20 columns. When I export a single line it opens fine, so apparently not every line has the issue.

Now I'm looking for advice on how to find the issue as Excel does not provide a line number (I HATE that!).

Anybody knows a tool or good method to validate a SpreadsheetML file?

Comment: I add my voice to yours to have a SpreadsheetML validator. it's a daunting task!!